# Display Each Setting Section In Each Specific Tab within Same Page || Settings API

Tags: settings-api

as everyone knows, when we want to display some setting section in some specific page, normally we must pass to it the slug-name of the page where we want to dispay it . it work 100% , but the problem that i faced is that when i wanted to work in just one Theme Page Option with Tabbed Navigation , i tried to follow the core rules so i did that to create two section and separate them with tabbed navigation in order to not interfere with the nonces . That's My Code .

```
        // These Are The registering settings for the Fields .
        register_setting( 'busymarket-header-settings', 'busymarkets-breadcrumb-setting' );
        register_setting( 'busymarket-footer-settings', 'busymarkets-main-footer-setting' );
        register_setting( 'busymarket-footer-settings', 'busymarkets-left-btm-footer-setting' );
        register_setting( 'busymarket-footer-settings', 'busymarkets-right-btm-footer-setting' );

        $active_tab = 'header_options';
        if ( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) { 
            if ( $_GET[ 'tab' ] == 'header_options' ) {
                $active_tab = 'header_options';
            } else if ( $_GET[ 'tab' ] == 'footer_options' ) {
                $active_tab = 'footer_options';
            }
        }

        <!-- Create A Tabbed Navigation For The Settings API -->
        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="<?php echo admin_url( '?page=busymarkets-theme-panel&tab=header_options' ); ?>" class="nav-tab<?php echo $active_tab == 'header_options' ? ' nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Header Options</a>
            <a href="<?php echo admin_url( '?page=busymarkets-theme-panel&tab=footer_options' ); ?>" class="nav-tab<?php echo $active_tab == 'footer_options' ? ' nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Footer Options</a>
        </h2>

        // The 'busymarket-header-settings' is The Option Group For The Header option .
        // The 'busymarket-footer-settings' is The Option Group For The Footer option .
        if ( $active_tab == 'footer_options' ) {
            // Footer Settings Registering .
            settings_fields( 'busymarket-footer-settings' );
            do_settings_sections( 'busymarkets-theme-panel' );

        } else if ( $active_tab == 'header_options' ) {
            // Footer Settings Registering .
            settings_fields( 'busymarket-header-settings' );
            do_settings_sections( 'busymarkets-theme-panel' );
        }

        submit_button();
```

The problem here is that actually the function `do_settings_sections()` Accepts the slug-name of the page where we want to output the section fields , and the fact that i'm using tab navigation i did a conditional code as you see below to not interfere with nonces and only display one section setting for every tab , But it didn't work .

I saw in a lot of tutorials that some developers work with a specific slug-name far from the slug-name of the page , whichever tab i click , i see the same section field , nothing happen and nothing changes .

So please, is there any solution to get thsi stuff work properly ?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Are you sure you are us using correct slug in `settings_field()`. Where is your `register_setting()`?

Comment: I did it , Wait i'm gonna edit the question , i just didn't apply i to the question

Comment: So far so good.  I didn't detect any error. I tried something similar and it worked even though settings are registered for different page slug. It should work. where is your add_settings_field??

Comment: Thanks Man for You respond , But i'm fully confident that all the functions are well coded , i just don't know where is the problem . Please do you have any idea how to solve this . i'm in need to keep on developing my theme .

Comment: I went through your code. I found no error. I tried similar tab with my already coded settings sections and pages it worked like charm. I have no clue on that now. Probably you should  check if the settings fields are registered to proper settings sections of settings id's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this huge Help , i appreciate that . i'll check on everything from the start . Just one thing ot be sure . i wanna ask you about the do_settings_sections() , everytime and anytime we use it we must pass to it just only the slug-page right ?

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone stumbles across this, I recently encountered the same issue and was able to render the differnet using `do_setting_fields( $page, $section )` instead of `do_settings_sections( $page )`.

As per the [settings api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), do_settings_sections prints out all settings sections added to a particular settings page, whilst do_settings_fields prints out the settings fields for a particular settings section.

Comment: You'll have to wrap the `do_settings_fields` call in a `<table class="form-table"></table>` to get the same markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the manual: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_section/

You can use the `$args['before_section']` and the `$args['after_section']` to wrap a section with e.g. `'<div class="tab-content">'.$section.'</div>'`. After that you only need the proper javascript code.

Another possible solution is giving a different `$page` for all the sections. In theory this variable should be the page slug, but in practice it can be anything.

Yet another option is using `do_setting_fields` with a table wrapper as Phil wrote.

What I prefer is the second and I use the form id, which is usually the plugin prefix, the storage id and the storage action e.g. `myplugin_mysettings_update`. I usually have one section for each form. When I store multiple entities in a settings option I append the entity id too e.g. `myplugin_mysettings_123_update`, so I can display all the update forms on a single page. I use the same form id as a prefix for input field ids so all input fields can have a unique id. I found that a single section for each tab is not the best solution.